# Laravel Homestead problems (Windows 10)

Tags: php, bash, laravel-5, homestead

I've combed through similar threads, but none are quite the same issue.  I've installed Homestead a handful of times now and seem to always have some kind of issue.

So I've created a www folder on my desktop and cloned the laravel/homsetead in there.  I "cd" into www/Homestead and run "bash init.sh" but it created the .homestead hidden folder containing Homestead.yaml, after.sh, and aliases file in my Windows "Users" directory.  I can copy/past the files into www/Homestead, edit the Homestead.yaml file accordingly, but then I get a slew of errors when I do vagrant up.  Any idea why the init shell file points to that directory and how that could be effecting things?

Comment: What does your paths in homestead.yaml look like?

Comment: I resolved this by cloning laravel/homestead in my user directory and adding a /Code folder.  init.sh ran fine and vagrant up worked without issue.  It's a curious thing though.  Prior to this install I was able to clone the homestead repository anywhere I wanted (i.e. in a directory on my desktop) and installation went fine.  Not on this one.

Answer (score 0):

> I resolved this by cloning laravel/homestead in my user directory and adding a /Code folder. init.sh ran fine and vagrant up worked without issue.??????

NONO,it doesn't work for me